# Xamarin.IOS date format

Tags: c#, ios, datetime, xamarin, ekevent

I am currently working on a app which should be able to scan some codes, QR etc.

However when I am scanning a VEVENT code the date format is looking like this:

> 20140713T190000Z

My question is basicly how I can convert this into a normal DateTime which I can use to add events to the calender?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a .Net DateTime from ISO 8601 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("20140713T190000Z","yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'",null);
```

also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029099/datetime-parse2012-09-30t230000-0000000z-always-converts-to-datetimekind-l)

Answer (score 4):

Try this for c#

```
NSDateFormatter dateFormat = new NSDateFormatter();
dateFormat.DateFormat = "d MMM yyyy";  
dateFormat.ToString(picker.Date);
```

Answer (score -2):

use following code:

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

    yourLabel.text=dateString;
```

Comment: Any posibility you could translate it to C#? :)

Comment: this code appears to format the current date into a string, which is not what the OP is asking about.