# c# convert string to date - what kind of format is this?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following DateTime string `2014-11-03 08:44:00:082467 Z`

When I try to do c simple `Convert.ToDateTime` I got and error that it's not a recognized DateTime string.

I also tried what's suggested in the post here: [DateTime.Parse("2012-09-30T23:00:00.0000000Z") always converts to DateTimeKind.Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029099/datetime-parse2012-09-30t230000-0000000z-always-converts-to-datetimekind-l)

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-09-30T23:00:00.0000000Z",
                                   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                   DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                   DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

But got the same error. What kind of DateTime string is this? and how can I convert it to a DateTime object? Also, it's not the currect time (I'm 2 hours before) - so I'm guessing it's some kind of universal time.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adjusting the date format string to match your data?

Comment: It's very odd to have a `:` before the subsecond value instead of a `.`

Comment: @PatrickHofman the code I posted is from another post that I found - it doesn't work on my string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format that applies to your `string`, although it is **not a valid string according to the [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) standard**:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-11-03 08:44:00:082467 Z",
                               "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss:ffffff' Z'",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                               DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

[Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/So1GlW)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format.

`DateTime.Now.ToString("o")`

Comment: so how do I make the conversion from string?

Comment: `DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);` will parse the time.  Any offsets that need to be applied I'll leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

The two dates you provide in your question are not the same at all !

Assuming your question applies to the second, which looks like to be standard, the answer is :

```
string s = "2012-09-30T23:00:00.0000000Z";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                   DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                   DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

(full working sample)