# How to convert string with a T and Z to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following string:

```
20150521T205510Z
```

How do I go about converting this to DateTime? Do I need to parse the date first then time? Or is there a way to plug this into DateTime.Parse() to get the correct value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var dateString = "20150521T205510Z";

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'",
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I referenced the answer from: [DateTime.Parse("2012-09-30T23:00:00.0000000Z") always converts to DateTimeKind.Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029099/datetime-parse2012-09-30t230000-0000000z-always-converts-to-datetimekind-l)

Comment: Thanks this made sense. I didnt know that there was a built in way to handle dates with other characters thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

Use function DateTime.ParseExact.

Additional information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I do not see in the MSDN page how to skip the T and the Z.

Comment: result = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateString, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);