# Convert plain string without seperator to date with format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff z'

Tags: c#, datetime-format

My `string` representation of *date time* is `"20181230183000000"` and I am *unable to convert* it to `DateTime`:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(DOCDate, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
```

Comment: `"ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff"` if the initial string *doesn't* have any *separators* so the pattern should do

Comment: Can we use string format for pattern

Answer (score 4):

Well, actual *format* and *pattern* should *match*: your current input

```
 20181230183000000
```

means

```
 yyyyMMddHHmmssfff
```

which stands for `year`, `month`, `day`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`, `fractions of second` all with *leading zeroes* and *without any separators*

**Code:**

```
  string DOCDate = "20181230183000000";

  DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
    DOCDate, 
    "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal); // Since you've mentioned 'z' in the question
```

Let's have a look

```
 Console.Write(result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  12/30/2018 18:30:00 +00:00
```

Similar code for `DateTime`:

```
  DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(
    DOCDate, 
    "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal); // Since you've mentioned 'z' in the question
```

Finally, if you want to *represent* `DateTimeOffset` (`DateTime`) in some format, use `ToString()` method:

```
  Console.Write(result.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff' z'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var dateTimeString = "20181230183000000";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                 DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dto))

{
     Console.WriteLine(dto);
}
```

Here is a good post on using DateTimeOffset, DateTime and not TimeZoneInfo

[DateTime.Parse("2012-09-30T23:00:00.0000000Z") always converts to DateTimeKind.Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029099/datetime-parse2012-09-30t230000-0000000z-always-converts-to-datetimekind-l)