Datetime in C# backend are losing timezone
I am creating a task in react frontend and it has some date fields. when I created a task I see the post call and the date fields showing in the post call as 2024-08-12T18:30:00.000Z now I am opening the task which is a get call and in the response I am only seeing 2024-08-12T18:30:00.
In the backend C# I am using
public DateTime? DateNow { get; set; }

I am missing the timezone "Z" in my GetCall, which I am seeing in my PostCall while creating the task.
How can I save the timeZone?

That’s the exact same date annd the object includes the knowledge it’s in UTC. What exactly are you missing here?

I am missing the timezone "Z" in my GetCall, which i am seeing in my PostCall while creating the task.

Yeah, don't use DateTime, use DateTimeOffset. You can use DateTime for UTC / Unknown dates, but Local doesn't make any sense in the era of internet services.


consider using also TimezoneInfo in case you'd like to reconstruct your local time. It can be helpful when you need to take into account daylight saving time settings.


@H_307 why do you assume you're missing anything? You posted only a formatted string that wasn't constructed with a Kind indicator. DateTime has no timezone, only a DateTimeKind indicator that's Local, UTC or Unknown. You'd only have an issue if DateTimeKind was Local. By default, ASP.NET Core/System.Text.Json deserialize Z as DateTimeKind.UTC and anything with an offset as Local. To avoid ambiguity though, use DateTimeOffset and explicitly store the offset

@JeremyLakeman not quite - the safest way is to store Local + IANA timezone name, eg 19:00 Europe/Berlin. The offset isn't enough, assuming UTC or even storing an offset fails if eg a country changes summer time rules (Russia, Egypt changed several times in the last decade). The IANA timezone names are the only standardized timezone names. Jon Skeet's Storing UTC isn't a silver bullet explains the issues with UTC and offsets

@PanagiotisKanavos that entirely depends on your use case. Future dates and calendar alarms have a lot of weird edge cases. For historical values though, preserving the users current time offset is sufficient. My point is that you should basically never use DateTime for anything other than UTC, and Local is useless and broken.... so long as you can assume a Gregorian calendar anyway.

In case this helps...
If what you see is via the ToString("o") keyword, make sure your DateTime object is set to DateTimeKind.Utc as well; as the DateTime object's kind may be Unspecified
var unspecified = new DateTime(2016, 12, 12, 10, 10, 10);
var specified = new DateTime(2016, 12, 12, 10, 10, 10, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine (unspecified.ToString("o")); // 2016-12-12T10:10:10.0000000
Console.WriteLine (specified.ToString("o")); // 2016-12-12T10:10:10.0000000Z

Standard date and time format strings

but i am not creating a new DateTime manually using c#, i am saving what's coming from the frontend. So how can i save the timezone while saving it in the backend.

I don't think I followed properly, you asked

post call and the date fields showing in the post call as 2024-08-12T18:30:00.000Z now I am opening the task which is a get call and in the response I am only seeing 2024-08-12T18:30:00.

You would send them in string and if it was stored as 'string' in DB, and grab, you would get what you saved, but you also mentioned public DateTime? DateNow { get; set; } then the mapping must happen somewhere.

I believe you are still parsing that string into a DateTime object somewhere, otherwise it means your string is manipulated somewhere.
But if there is a use case of parsing date, you want to use ParseExact instead

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029183/12714500

